# OLE DB reported a change in schema version between compile time and run time error

Tags: sql, sql-server, oledb, sql-server-2016, linked-server

I have a query which is working for archive & delete. The Stored procedure is getting data from linked server into another server. Then sp is deleting inserted rows from source server.

```
--Table_B and A parameterized. They can change with parameter

INSERT INTO [Server_1].[DB_1].[dbo].[Table_A_1] (ColumnList1) 
--ColumnList has a lot of columns like Column1,Column2
SELECT ColumnList FROM [Server_2].[DB_2].[dbo].[Table_B_1] WHERE (Condition);
DELETE FROM [Server_2].[DB_2].[dbo].[Table_B_1] WHERE (Condition);


INSERT INTO [Server_1].[DB_1].[dbo].[Table_A_2] (ColumnList1) 
SELECT ColumnList FROM [Server_2].[DB_2].[dbo].[Table_B_2] WHERE (Condition);
DELETE FROM [Server_2].[DB_2].[dbo].[Table_B_2] WHERE (Condition);


INSERT INTO [Server_1].[DB_1].[dbo].[Table_A_3] (ColumnList1) 
SELECT ColumnList FROM [Server_2].[DB_2].[dbo].[Table_B_3] WHERE (Condition);
DELETE FROM [Server_2].[DB_2].[dbo].[Table_B_3] WHERE (Condition);


INSERT INTO [Server_1].[DB_1].[dbo].[Table_A] (ColumnList1) 
SELECT ColumnList FROM [Server_2].[DB_2].[dbo].[Table_B] WHERE (Condition);
DELETE FROM [Server_2].[DB_2].[dbo].[Table_B] WHERE (Condition);
```

When i manually run the sp usually it is working. But sometimes the sp is giving error as below. Also when i try to run sp from a windows service it is giving error often. Table_B_1,Table_B_2 and Table_B_3 are collecting (they are data for Table_B as numbers,files etc.) but Table_B (main and important table) is not collecting.

The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "Server_2" reported a change in schema version between compile time ("185688636079091") and run time ("185718681838570") for table ""DB_2"."dbo"."Table_B"".

If i started service working over 50-60 times with parameters around 10 table is archiving but the others not. I need a solution for this.

SQL Server Versions are same. One machine is snapshot machine. Versions are :

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2498818/fix-error-7359-when-you-run-a-query-against-a-user-defined-function-or  what versions of sql server?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64) they are same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OLE DB provider for linked server reported a change in schema version Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575975/ole-db-provider-for-linked-server-reported-a-change-in-schema-version-error)

Answer (score 1):

Same question on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575975/ole-db-provider-for-linked-server-reported-a-change-in-schema-version-error).

Solutions are:
1. Install Microsoft fix that Mitch Wheat suggested
2. Remove the table alias
3. Run `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE WITH NO_INFOMSGS;` (Explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-freeproccache-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017))

Comment: If you notice that a question is a duplicate, please flag it as such.